# How do i get the key at a specific index in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

So i need a function to delete a key at a specific index.
Is there a built-in function which does that, or do i have to do it on my own ?

Example:

```
my_dict={"bus":"2$","uber":"5$","taxi":"5$"}

var1 = my_dict.function(0)
var2 = my_dict.function(2)
var3 = my_dict.function(1)
```

In this case, var1 would be "bus", var2 would be "taxi" and var3 would be "uber".

Comment: If you're trying to deal with elements by index, a dictionary is probably the wrong structure to be using.

Comment: No. dictionaries don't have numeric indexes that exist apart from the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn all the keys into a list then index based on that.

```
my_dict={"bus":"2$","uber":"5$","taxi":"5$"}
var1 = list(my_dict.keys())[0]
```

out

```
bus
```